# Android fails to build on OS X 10.7

Tags: android, macos, javac, xcode4.5, android-source

I am trying to build the android source main branch with GNU gcc 4.7.
Everything worked until I updated to Xcode 4.5.
It seems to be a java-related or permission-related problem.
I double checked and all the directories are writable and `javac` (1.6.0_37) works fine.

This is my configuration information

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-12.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
```

but I get this error

```
Install: out/host/darwin-x86/bin/acp
host Java: antlr-runtime (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/antlr-runtime_intermediates/classes)
target Java: core (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes)
host Java: dx (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/dx_intermediates/classes)
external/jsr305/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/CheckForNull.java:14: error while writing javax.annotation.CheckForNull: could not create parent directories
public @interface CheckForNull {
        ^
1 error
make: *** [out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/jsr305lib_intermediates/javalib.jar] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
external/antlr/antlr-3.4/runtime/Java/src/main/java/org/antlr/runtime/ANTLRStringStream.java:37: error while writing org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream: could not create parent directories
public class ANTLRStringStream implements CharStream {
       ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
make: *** [out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/antlr-runtime_intermediates/javalib.jar] Error 41
dalvik/dx/src/com/android/dx/Version.java:22: error while writing com.android.dx.Version: could not create parent directories
public class Version {
       ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
make: *** [out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/dx_intermediates/javalib.jar] Error 41
libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/Object.java:131: error while writing java.lang.Object: could not create parent directories
public class Object {
       ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
```

Comment: did you try a clean build? I wonder if the new Xcode could not support previously compiled source

Comment: Yes I did. I think That's a Java compiler related issue. I am now compiling in an Ubuntu VM and everything is working so far.

Comment: I recommend answering your own question then, in case other people run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue very close to this one.

> ============================================ PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL PLATFORM_VERSION=4.3.2.1.000.000
>   TARGET_PRODUCT=full TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
>   TARGET_BUILD_APPS= TARGET_ARCH=arm TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
>   TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic HOST_ARCH=x86 HOST_OS=darwin
>   HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-12.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
>   BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER OUT_DIR=out
>   ============================================ target Java: telephony-common
>   (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/telephony-common_intermediates/classes)
>   target Strip: libLLVM (out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libLLVM.so)
>   target Symbolic: libGLES_trace
>   (out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/lib/libGLES_trace.so)
>   target Symbolic: libui
>   (out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/lib/libui.so) target
>   Symbolic: libbinder
>   (out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/lib/libbinder.so) target
>   Strip: dalvik-vm-unit-tests
>   (out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/dalvik-vm-unit-tests_intermediates/dalvik-vm-unit-tests)
>   target Strip: libemoji
>   (out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libemoji.so) target Strip:
>   libsqlite (out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libsqlite.so) target
>   Strip: libsonivox (out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libsonivox.so)
>   target Strip: libharfbuzz_ng
>   (out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libharfbuzz_ng.so) target Strip:
>   libharfbuzz (out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/libharfbuzz.so)
>   Install: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/libemoji.so Install:
>   out/target/product/generic/system/lib/libLLVM.so Install:
>   out/target/product/generic/system/lib/libsonivox.so Install:
>   out/target/product/generic/system/lib/libsqlite.so target Package:
>   ApplicationsProvider
>   (out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/ApplicationsProvider_intermediates/package.apk)
>   target Package: BackupRestoreConfirmation
>   (out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/BackupRestoreConfirmation_intermediates/package.apk)
>   target Package: BasicDreams
>   (out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/BasicDreams_intermediates/package.apk)
>   frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/PhoneFactory.java:130:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : variable PREFERRED_CDMA_SUBSCRIPTION
>   location: class android.provider.Settings.Global
>                                   Settings.Global.PREFERRED_CDMA_SUBSCRIPTION,
>                                                  ^ Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for
>   details. 1 error make: ***
>   [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/telephony-common_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar]
>   Error 41 make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

The issue turned out to be I didn't properly follow instructions at first. It was on a case sensitive filesystem, per the android setup instructions, but I had copied it over from the normal filesystem. After I re-ran repo sync it compiled.

If this sounds like your issues, following http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html :

> hdiutil create -type SPARSE -fs 'Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+' -size
>   40g ~/android.dmg
>
> hdiutil attach ~/android.dmg.sparseimage -mountpoint /Volumes/android
>
> mv ~/android-source /Volumes/android
>
> cd /Volumes/android/android-source
>
> repo sync
>
> make -j4